# Definition of a system of recurrent events

Tags: probability-theory

I am reading the paper *A note on the Borel-Cantelli lemma* by Kochen and Stone. They say:

> *A sequence $E_1, E_2, \ldots$ is called a system of recurrent events if there exist independent and identically distributed positive-integer valued random variables $Y_1, Y_2, \ldots$ such that $E_k$ is the event that $Y_1 + \ldots + Y_j = k$ for some $j$.*

Later on they give an example:

> *Let $E_k$ be the event that the simple random walk in one dimension is at the origin at time $2k$. The $E_k$ form a system of recurrent events ...*

I can't reconcile the example with the given definition. What could the sequence $Y_1, Y_2, \ldots$ be in the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

James Martin was kind enough to provide a nice answer when I posted this [question on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366414/definition-of-a-system-of-recurrent-events). I'll repeat it here for completeness:

Put $T_0 = 0$, put $T_i$ to be the time of the $i$-th return of the random walk to the origin for $i = 1, 2, \ldots$, and put $Y_i = T_i - T_{i-1}$ for $i = 1, 2, \ldots$. Then the $Y_i$ are independent and identically distributed and a random walk is at the origin at time $k$ iff $Y_1 + \ldots + Y_j = k$ for some $j$.

Many thanks to James.